# having issues on sending email in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

I am having issues on sending email via notification. I tried accessing the mailbox using the credentials I put in .env, the credential is good I am able to access the inbox but if I run the command sending email is failed.

on my .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=myhost
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=this@isworkingemail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=pWdisWorking
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=this@isworkingemail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME='AFTSCredit'
```

[image]

my function via

```
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return [TwilioChannel::class,'database','mail']; 
    // return [TwilioChannel::class,'database']; 
}
```

any idea? plase help thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using queue job to send email? Are you using gmail smtp? It could be due to various factors. Sometimes mails dont reach inboxes specially hotmail. Try sending it to gmail. Are you sending it from your local computer or a server?

Comment: Check your .env file vs email.php file inside config folder. they might be conflicting each other. You might not have specified to use .env variables in config. You might have cached your config file..Just clear all your cache

Comment: hi @DeepeshThapa I am not using gmail just the siteground's mail. I do using queue but I disabled it and will enable it after this issues fixed. I haven't check the config (where in config i should look at?) and i already run the config:clear and cache:clear

Comment: Check my answer below. If you still find problem, Lets get down to business and get it done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says Authentication error. This is nothing to do with Laravel/PHP mailer. 
Try one of these below:

- Clear cache
- Check if you have modified config file. Make sure your .env variables are being pointed in your config file
- Check if your server allows outbound emails
- Check if you have right credentials such as host name, username, password
- If you need extra authentication to allow using smtp services like google. You will need to activate to allow to use less secure app.

Finally, but not the least

> If your mail server password contains a # then you should quote the environment string since everything after # will be taken as comment (starting in Laravel 5.8)

Comment: adding quote  in the password works for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

put the port and host as follows

```
MAIL_PORT = 587
MAIL_HOST= smtp.gmail.com
```

and also in your gmail . Disable two authentication and enabled unsecured apps 
and then it would be okkay